# testing click python applications

Tags: python, python-click

click is a python package for creating nice commandline interfaces for your applications. I have been playing with click a bit and today pushed this [simple](https://github.com/jetbird/toroman) roman numeral converter on github.

What I want to do now is to test my click application. I am reading through the documentation, but don't know how to run the tests.

Does anyone have experience with testing click applications?

Comment: So put tests inside toroman.py and run it? I have tried but it does not   work.

Comment: From the [Testing](http://click.pocoo.org/3/testing/) chapter in the docs, it looks like you can write tests as separate scripts that use `click.testing.CliRunner`, and then you run the tests just by running those scripts the same as any other Python script. What part of that is confusing? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Yes, but when I run the python file that contains the tests I don't get any output to tell me if they passed or failed.

Comment: OK, then show us a simple example of a `click` app and `CliRunner` tests, and how you're running them, don't make us guess at what you did and what parts you may or may not understsand.

Answer (score 18):

Putting the code below in `test_greet.py`:

```
import click
from click.testing import CliRunner

def test_greet():
    @click.command()
    @click.argument('name')
    def greet(name):
        click.echo('Hello %s' % name)

    runner = CliRunner()
    result = runner.invoke(greet, ['Sam'])
    assert result.output == 'Hello Sam\n'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_greet()
```

If simply called with `python test_greet.py` the tests pass and nothing is shown. When used in a testing framework, it performs as expected. For example `nosetests test_greet.py` returns

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK
```

Comment: This example function works as expected if embedded in testing framework like `nose` or `pytest` [see example in click](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/click/blob/master/tests/test_testing.py)

Comment: This is just an example of a tiny in-line function how do I test a script that uses click??

Answer (score 2):

`pytest` has the handlers for the asserts.

To run tests against an existing script, it must be 'imported'.

```
import click
from click.testing import CliRunner
from click_app import configure, cli

def test_command_configure():
    runner = CliRunner()
    result = runner.invoke(cli, ["configure"])
    assert result.exit_code == 0
    assert result.output == 'configure'
```

Comment: Would you consider adding source for 'click_app.py' to complete the example?